# WPF ListView Как заставить поле занять оставшееся пространство?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, xaml, gridview

Имеется следующий ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}" 
          MaxHeight="250" 
          util:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True" 
          AlternationCount="2"
          SizeChanged="ListView_SizeChanged">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF8F8F8" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Название" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Name"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Главы" Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProgressCh}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Тома" Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProgressVol}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Оценка" util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Score" Width="70">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Тип" util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Kind" Width="70">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Kind}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Отображается он вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы узнать, как настроить столбцы так, чтобы все кроме первого столбца занимали ширину по содержимому самого широкого элемента, а первый столбец занимал всё оставшееся пространство.

Установка Width="Auto" как -то не помогла. Второй и Третий столбцы всё равно урезаются. Плюс появляется горизонтальный Scroll, за которым скрыт последний столбец =(

Подскажите как подобное можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Для этого случая на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309249/listview-gridviewcolumn-width) предлагают немного магии: добавить `Grid` с соответствующим количеством колонок, который и будет осуществлять ресайз, перекрёстно связать ширины через биндинги и радоваться. Для фиксации ширин колонок от редактирования добавлю от себя стиль для `GridViewColumnHeader`, в котором стоит `IsEnabled = "False"`.

Ваша разметка без привязки к данным и других лишних вещей:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="HeaderStyle"
                   TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                        Value="False" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="col1"
                                    Header="Название"
                                    Width="{Binding ElementName=helperField, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="col2"
                                    Header="Главы"
                                    Width="Auto"
                                    HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="col3"
                                    Header="Тома"
                                    Width="Auto"
                                    HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="col4"
                                    Header="Оценка"
                                    Width="Auto"
                                    HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="col5"
                                    Header="Тип"
                                    Width="Auto"
                                    HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        Test Text
    </ListView>
    <Grid Visibility="Hidden">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col2, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col3, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col4, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col5, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0"
              x:Name="helperField" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

У всех колонок в `ListView` кроме первой стоит `Width=Auto`, в управляющем невидимом `Grid` соответствующие колонки привязаны к `ActualWidth` колонок `ListView`. Первая колонка в `Grid` имеет ширину "*", значит занимает оставшееся пространство. В `Grid` лежит в первой колонке элемент, `ActualWidth` которого привязана к первой колонке `ListView`. Также в `Grid` есть 10-пиксельная колонка для того, чтобы не отображался горизонтальный скрол по умолчанию.

Решение, конечно, попахивает, но тем не менее работает, и работает только из разметки.

Comment: не совсем пока понимаю, куда же привязывать содержимое? сделать  `GridViewColumn` парным тегом и как у меня реализовано или же в скрытом гриде привязка?

Comment: @Mr.Modest, вам нужно просто добавить в свой код все новое из моего. Положить ListView в Grid, в самом ListView в соответствующих элементах добавить недостающие свойства из моего кода, под ListView добавить невидимый Grid, просто скопировав его.

Comment: @Mr.Modest, обновит коммент.

Comment: сделал.. и.. не совсем то: http://pastexen.com/i/9yhMNzzMOc.png

Comment: как я понял, колонки подстроились под ширину заголовков и всё..

Comment: @Mr.Modest, да, они о заголовку, а не по содержимому отресайзились. Я тупанул. Чуть позже посмотрю, как поправить.

Comment: а горизонтальный скролл почему появился? =/

Comment: @Mr.Modest, надо тестить. Чуть позже.

Comment: ещё одна деталь... сортировка по всем колонкам, кроме первой не работает.. у меня по клику по заголовку была сортировка списка по этой колонке :(

Comment: окей.. я просто пишу, что замечаю, пока помню)

Comment: @Mr.Modest, все колонки кроме первой заблокированы через стиль, чтобы их нельзя было ресайзить. Иначе это делается сильно сложнее. Посмотрю тоже.

Comment: уже обратил на это внимание, да :) запрет резайса не критичен.. сортировка важнее, даже если запрета резайса не будет, главное чтобы изначальная ширина была нормальной у колонок)

Comment: установил колонкам фиксированные значения.. в принципе работает.. при резайзе окна, раздвигается только первая, остальные не меняются, если не менять специально их..

Answer (score 0):

Естественно, Auto не работает, потому что оно делает ширину равной максимальной ширине элемента; а других спецзначений у ширины нет. Вы, тем не менее, можете попробовать сделать следующее:

- Установить у всех колонок, кроме первой, Width=Auto
- Добавить обработчик события SizeChanged:

_

```
private void ListView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = sender as ListView;
    GridView gView = listView.View as GridView;

    var totalWidth = listView.ActualWidth - (SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth+10); 

    var usedWidth = 0.0;    
    for(int i=1;i<gView.Columns.Count;i++){
        usedWidth+=gView.Columns[i].ActualWidth;
    }

    gView.Columns[0].Width = totalWidth-usedWidth;

}
```

(Также этот код надо вызвать при изменении содержимого списка).

Comment: зафиксировал 2 последних столбца в width=70, 2 других поставил в width=auto, а первому ничего не задавал и установил ваш обработчик..  столбцы с auto почему-то ужаты по ширине заголовка, в итоге их контент урезается, а первая колонка даже при этом берёт больше места чем есть и появляется горизонтальный scroll =(  вот скриншот: http://pastexen.com/i/zczHXEd73q.png

Comment: вам нужно сделать, чтобы код из обработчика SizeChanged также вызывался при изменении содержимого ListView

Comment: Поправка: при расчете ширины вместо SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth надо взять с запасом в 10 пикселей: (SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth+10). Иначе столбцы не поместяться в ширину ListView.

Comment: >"также вызывался при изменении содержимого" - что-то не могу понять к какому ещё событию привязать этот обработчик для этого =/ не нахожу никаких ItemChange или ContentChange =(

Comment: Это смотря как приложение вообще построено. Например, можно в модели сделать событие PropertyChanged. Или просто в коде после любого изменения явно вызывать этот метод.

Comment: у меня в VM списки из ObservableCollection. Они привязаны к ListView. Так что удаление и добавление элементов моментально отображается.

Comment: только вот поля всё равно ужимаются по заголовку, вместо контента =/

Comment: У ObservableCollection есть события CollectionChanged и PropertyChanged, видимо их и надо обрабатывать. "_только вот поля всё равно ужимаются по заголовку, вместо контента_ " - странно, я создал почти такую же разметку и у меня ужимется по контенту. Я только убрал util потому что я не знаю что это такое.

Comment: util это из класса для сортировки по заголовкам

Comment: listview вложен в tabcontrol с фиксированной высотой (300), тот в StackPanel, а тот в DockPanel и выше только Window у которого Height="600" Width="450"