# ListView как шаблон TabControl. Вертикальный скрол без фиксированной высоты

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, xaml, mvvm

Есть следующий UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Name="mangaTabsControl" 
             x:Class="ShikiDesk.Controls.MangaTabsControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ShikiDesk.ViewModel"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:main="clr-namespace:ShikiDesk"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShikiDesk.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Background="#FFF8F8F8">
    <TabControl SelectedIndex="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Manga.Tabs}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserStatusRus}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}" 
                          AlternationCount="2"
                          SelectedIndex="0"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.Manga.SelectedView, ElementName=mangaTabsControl, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridView.Columns>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Название" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MainName}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Главы" Width="Auto">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProgressChapters}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Тома" Width="Auto">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProgressVolumes}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="35">
                                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                                        <Image Source=".../ico.png" />
                                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Тип" Width="70">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Kind}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView.Columns>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</UserControl>
```

В нём в качестве ContentTemplate выступает ListView. Явно значение высоты установленно только у Window, в котором будет находиться данный UserControl.

Наглядно вложенность (упрощено).

Главное окно:

```
<Window Width="value" Height="value">
    <DockPanel>
        <! -- Some Controls -->
        <controls:UserControl_Main DockPanel.Dock="Top"/> <! -- необходимый контрол вложен в этот -->
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

UserControl_Main:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" MinHeight="200">
        <!-- Some Controls -->
    </StackPanel>

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,3">
        <!-- Some Controls -->
    </DockPanel>

    <local:MangaTabsControl Grid.Row="2" x:Name="MTabsControl" /> <!-- расписанный выше UserControl -->
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не отображается вертикальный скролл. 
Игнорирует значение высоты окна и идёт вниз до упора. 
Из-за этого возникает и другая проблема - подтормаживание при переключении вкладок. 
Скролл отображается, если зафиксировать высоты TabControl или Listview, но это мне не подходит. 
Пробовал разные решения из гугла для ListView, но они не работают. Видимо из-за того, что ListView не самостоятельный контрол, а шаблон для TabControl..

Аналогично игнорирует границы окна и в горизонтальном положении =/

**UPD:** Ответ есть вот в этом вопросе: ["Железные" рамки для контролов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654841/%D0%96%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: @VladD, пытался пригласить вас в час, но не уверен, что сделал это правильно.. попробую ещё раз другим способом.. 
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56675/listview--datatemplate

Comment: Я был в отпуске :) Ничего, разберёмся сейчас.

Comment: @VladD оу.. надеюсь хорошо отдохнули.. я уж боялся, что слишком навязываюсь вам и вы решили меня игнорировать =D

Comment: Не, всё в порядке. Все проблемы решим, WPF вообще суперский фреймворк.

Comment: в чем проблема-то? Grid все решает же. StackPanel бесконечный в ширину или высоту. Grid позволяет настраивать ширину и высоту как вам угодно и влияет на ширину/высоту внутренних элементов.

Comment: @dm.dymov а можно на примере, если не сложно?

Comment: @Mr.Modest совет: забудьте о `StackPanel` совсем, из-за него вы можете получить много неожиданных на первый взгляд результатов.

Comment: @Mr.Modest, в соседнем вашем вопросе пример запостил.

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Как ваш этот вопрос, всё ещё не решён?

Comment: @VladD спасибо. Г-н dm.dymov мне помог с этой задачей. Ответил в том вопросе правда, а не в этом :D. Сейчас я пытаюсь разобраться с колонками..

Comment: @VladD вот тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640980/wpf-listview-Как-заставить-поле-занять-оставшееся-пространство

Comment: @VladD вы случайно не знаете ответ на тот вопрос?)

Comment: @Mr.Modest: На _тот_ или на _этот_?

Comment: @VladD со скроллом проблему решил) вопрос с шириной столбцов в ListView.. пока решил проблему фиксированными значениями, ибо если пытаться выравнивать ширину по содержимому, то выравниваются только по заголовкам..

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Если вы решили эту проблему, может быть, напишите кратко ответ здесь? Чтобы будущие поколения читали.

Comment: @VladD я так и сделал) подредактировал вопрос.. хотел написать в ответе, но СО не разрешил мне в ответе дать ссылку на другой вопрос в СО =/

Comment: @Mr.Modest: А вы напишите без ссылки (или добавьте в середину пробел), а я отредактирую как надо.

Comment: @VladD сделал)......(ещё 15 символов для СО)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ есть вот в этом вопросе: ["Железные" рамки для контролов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654841/%D0%96%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Проблема была в том, что StackPanel имеет свойство расширяться до бесконечности, отсюда и контролы в нём уходили в бесконечность. Стоило заменить внешний StackPanel на Grid и картина сразу стала симпатичнее и ListView самостоятельно закрепился за нижней границей окна)

Comment: Отлично, но вы бы всё же написали два слова по теме: как именно решилась проблема.

Comment: @VladD описал примерный ход мыслей)

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!