# "Железные" рамки для контролов

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Есть ли панель, в которую можно было бы запихнуть Control'ы, которые не смогут выходить за пределы этой панели, Margin которых будет отсчитываться от границ этой панели и при этом, эта панель должна быть "резиновой"?

Если честно, у меня уже мозги взрываются от логики XAML. Понимаю, что возможно уход контрола за границы окна кому-то может быть нужен, но неужели без жёсткой фиксации высоты и ширины нельзя научить контролы правильно обтекать окно/панель?

К примеру, TextBlock отказывался переходить на новую строчку, пока я не задал жёстко границу панели, в которой он находится, при этом, если я пробую изменять ширину панели, текст не адаптируется под новую ширину, а остаётся неизменным (очевидно, это потому что я был вынужден фиксировать ширину панели и она более не реагирует на изменение окна).

Аналогично, вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645985/listview-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-tabcontrol-%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B) я пытался понять почему ListView уходит за пределы окна и какой в этом смысл. А главное понять, как исправить поведение. К сожалению, никто не отреагировал на вопрос и я всё ещё в тупике.

Comment: А что значит «резиновой»? Покажите желаемое поведение, придумаем, что можно сделать.

Comment: И кстати, чем вам не подходит просто `Grid`?

Comment: @VladD в случае с TextBlock это текст обтекает границы реалтайм, т.е. если мы увеличили ширину окна, то текст "растекается" на новую ширину.В случае с LisView, то нижняя его граница должна быть привязана к нижней границе окна, а если количество элементов превыщает помещаемое, то появлялся скрол. Также при изменении высоты окна, высота ListView также должна увеличиваться, вмещая в себя больше отображаемых элементов...

Comment: @VladD вы же мне и советовали использовать ListView =D плюс ко всему, мне нужно знать выделенный элемент

Comment: Ничего не понятно :) Да, ListView можно заставить растягиваться вместе с окном. Покажите ваш код (желательно упрощённый пример).

Comment: @VladD по той ссылке есть код. По идее, убрал оттуда всё, что, на мой взгляд, не влияет на разметку..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то вам нужно использовать `Grid`. `StackPanel`, которую вы скорей всего используете, бесконечна в ширину или высоту для внутренних элементов, она просто обрезает представление внутренних элементов, не влияя на их ширины/высоты, не вызывая trimming у `TextBlock`, например. `Grid` же позволяет настроить ширины/высоты строк/колонок как вам нравится.

Например:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="1 1" />
    <TextBlock Text="1 2 Эта колонка занимает всю оставшуюся ширину"
               Grid.Column="1"
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1">
        <sys:String>2 1 Этот</sys:String>
        <sys:String>ListBox</sys:String>
        <sys:String>узкий</sys:String>
        <sys:String>но занимает</sys:String>
        <sys:String>всю оставшуюся</sys:String>
        <sys:String>высоту.</sys:String>
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="1">
        <sys:String>2 2 Этот</sys:String>
        <sys:String>ListBox</sys:String>
        <sys:String>широкий</sys:String>
        <sys:String>и высокий.</sys:String>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Стоит отметить, что по умолчанию у всех элементов `Grid.Row` и `Grid.Column` равны 0.

Попробуйте потаскать окно. `TextBlock` в верхней колонке будет тримиться, а у `ListBox` появятся скролы.

Comment: убрал фиксированную высоту... создал Grid с трёмя строками, третьей задал Height="*", в ней же поместил описываемый в том вопросе UserControl. почти получилось, скролл появился, но нижняя границы не доходит до дна окна (http://pastexen.com/i/Kwr7DGxH1x.png)

Comment: может быть проблема в том, что у меня не просто ListView, а ListView идёт как DataTemplate для ContentTemplate TabControl'а ?

Comment: @Mr.Modest, попробуйте вашему контролу поставить VerticalAlingnment=Stretch.

Comment: у него эти значения по умолчанию.. в любом случае, задал явно, результата никакого.. видимо проблема в том, что ListView это шаблон, а не сам контрол..

Comment: @Mr.Modest, есть ощущение, что у вас получается две строки нижние, у которых у обеих стоит Height=*. * - это занять одну часть оставшейся высоты. Если у двух строк это стоит, они будут занимать по половине оставшейся высоты.

Comment: к слову, сам описываемый UserControl я не менял, Grid я добавил во внешний UserControl, который подключает его..

Comment: @Mr.Modest, что у вас в каждой из трех строк? у UserControl какое стоит значение Grid.Row?

Comment: подправил тот вопрос.. посмотрите в UserControl_Main:

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57254/discussion-between-dm-dymov-and-mr-modest).